# What are the effects of sipping blood?

Tags: side-effects, blood

Since childhood, I've noticed that when most people get injured they tend to sip the blood from where they got injured claiming that they are doing so, so as not to waste the blood, and furthermore saying that it's better to return the blood back to the body by sipping it.

Since then, I began to wonder if doing such has any side effects. I've never tried it, because as a medical student, it seems inappropriate and very irritating. So in a nutshell,

**Does sipping the blood have any side-effects or health benefits?**

Comment: The effect of ingesting the small amout of blood that comes out of a minor cut or injury is negligible, especially since you can't get any new disease from your own blood. Also, you can't "recycle" blood by sipping it, it will just get digested like anything else. Besides, your body is more than able of handling a loss of a couple mililiters so there's no piont in trying to get that blood back so badly.

Comment: Harmless. The same amount of blood probably leaks into your GI tract every day.